# Embedding multiple user controls into a page?

Tags: asp.net

I've embedded multiple user controls into the same page. The user controls typically have 2 different views, an edit/default view and a completed view. When the user completes an edit then I switch the MultiView to the completed state. This pattern works okay in pages.

The problem is when I go back to the master view/page then the user brings back the control, the view is still in the completed state.

What are some simple methods for resetting/correcting the multiview state? I could have a Reset() function on every control but it feels like I may be able to avoid that.

Update:

This page is designed to show an account/profile view and it has the following parts:

```
<asp:MultiView>
...read only view 
<asp:EmailEditView>
<asp:AccountEditView>
```

etc..

And then each of those views has a user control. Inside the user control, we have something like this

```
<asp:multiview>
<asp:view id="edit"/>
<asp:view id="completed"/>
```

I've found the following problems with this design:

1. When the user completes an action of user control such as changing an email. The view stays in the finished state even when they go back to it a second time.
2. When the user goes back to the original form the data is stale. This design really screws with the postback mechanism. If I don't use !IsPostBack on the main form for databding then my dropdownlist on the sub forms will not work. However, once I add the !isPostBack on the main form then the data becomes stale.

I can add a "reset" flag to every user control and add something like this

```
if ((!IsPostback) || (reset) )
```

As well as resetting the view. In the other scenario, I can add an event handler to load the reload/bind the data when the user clicks "back", i.e where I change the form back.

Comment: what mechanism are you using to store what state your controls are in? can we see some code perhaps?

Comment: I have no idea what "The problem is when I go back to the master view/page then the user brings back the control, the view is still in the completed state." means.

Comment: @Greg I think that embedding the user controls into the page like this for form editing is a bad idea because now I must track the state of the user control.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to recreate the functionality of your problem while taking out the complexity of user controls.  Here's my best guess so far (please correct me if I'm wrong)

```
<asp:MultiView runat="server" ID="MainMultiView" ActiveViewIndex="0">
    <asp:View runat="server" ID="DefaultView">
        Default View
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="EditEmailButton" Text="Edit Email" OnClick="EditEmailButton_Click" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="EditAccountButton" Text="Edit Account" OnClick="EditAccountButton_Click" />
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View runat="server" ID="EmailView">
        <asp:MultiView runat="server" ID="EmailMultiView" ActiveViewIndex="0">
            <asp:View runat="server" ID="EmailEditView">
                Edit Email
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SaveEmailButton" Text="Save" 
                    onclick="SaveEmailButton_Click" />
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="CancelEmailButton" Text="Cancel" 
                    onclick="CancelEmailButton_Click" />
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View runat="server" ID="EmailCompleteView">
                Email Edit Complete!
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View runat="server" ID="AccountView">
        <asp:MultiView runat="server" ID="AccountMultiView" ActiveViewIndex="0">
            <asp:View runat="server" ID="AccountEditView">
                Edit Account
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SaveAccountButton" Text="Save" 
                    onclick="SaveAccountButton_Click" />
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="CancelAccountButton" Text="Cancel" 
                    onclick="CancelAccountButton_Click" />
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View runat="server" ID="AccountCompleteView">
                Account Edit Complete!
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

-- code behind

```
protected void EditEmailButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainMultiView.SetActiveView(EmailView);
}

protected void EditAccountButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainMultiView.SetActiveView(AccountView);
}

protected void SaveEmailButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save();
    EmailMultiView.SetActiveView(EmailCompleteView);
}

protected void CancelEmailButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EmailMultiView.SetActiveView(EmailCompleteView);
}

protected void SaveAccountButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save();
    AccountMultiView.SetActiveView(AccountCompleteView);
}

protected void CancelAccountButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AccountMultiView.SetActiveView(AccountCompleteView);
}
```

Comment: Once I click "save" or "cancel", I can't go back to the default view to select another view though.  Maybe you could post a http://www.screentoaster.com/ of your page and its workflow?

Comment: No, I can "go back" to the main form. However, remember it will have something to this effect if !postback. So the data won't load. See my update for how I'm handling it.

Comment: I added a Reset() method to every user control which is called before I call the user control. This updates the form and sets a boolean and on PageLoad, I have if (!Postback) || (ifReset) -- this is required to reload the data on the user controls too.